# huggingface - pegasus PegasusTokenizer is None

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Trying to use [tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase](https://huggingface.co/tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase). Followed the examples in [Pegasus](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/pegasus.html).

> The Pegasus model was proposed in PEGASUS: Pre-training with Extracted Gap-sentences for Abstractive Summarization by Jingqing Zhang, Yao Zhao, Mohammad Saleh and Peter J. Liu on Dec 18, 2019.

**Problem:**

PegasusTokenizer cannot be instantiated as `PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)` returns `None`. Using the 'google/pegasus-xsum' as the model name caused the same.

```
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer
model_name = 'tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase'
tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

type(tokenizer)
---
NoneType
```

Please suggest how to work it around.

Comment: did you download the models before using them?

Answer (score 4):

You need to install sentence piece library needed for tokenizer to work properly. To install it run:

```
pip install sentencepiece
```

Actually the error occurred because you imported the tokenizer first before installing sentencepiece and after receiving the error you installed it without restarting the session.
Make sure you install sentence piece before importing the tokenizer.